# Send push notifications in android using api from parse

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, parse-platform

I am currently working on an android app for a client and it needs to use push notifications from parse.com. I have been able to send notifications from the emulator and also receive messages from the server when someone sends a message from there but I want to do it in such a way such that the server automatically sends me a notification depending on a condition. Is it possible and if yes, could someone direct as to how to do it.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this pro grammatically? Not just using the console?

Comment: @Jeris fyi parse.com has been [discontinued](http://news.softpedia.com/news/facebook-decides-to-discontinue-parse-out-of-the-blue-499606.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Your client would need to notice the condition and send the message.
What event did you trigger a notification from?

Comment: i am parsing from a xml file in the net and if the date attribute changes i need to notify the user using thru push notifications, but my doubt is that can if the the server can automatically send the notification depending on the change in the date.

Comment: You have two options here:
1. Your client which modifies the XML file can send the push notification as well using the [iOS](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#push) or [Android](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#push) APIs
2. If you own the server which is hosting the XML file, you can send the push notification using the [REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest#push)

Comment: so its like automatically it(notifications) cant be sent using the android api other than manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yoou can use Parse Cloud Code. If you have your XML parsing code in a 3rd party server, make an external call to the 3d party server through REST from Parse Cloud Code. Inside your Parse Cloud Code you can check the date attribute changes, and if your condition is met, you can send push notification from the Parse Cloud Code. So your android application should communicate only with the Parse Cloud Code and let the cloud code talk to your 3rd party server.